# Comparing dimensionality

Tags: asymptotics, high-dimensional

I am reading a couple of papers, 
The first one claims that $p_n = O(n^a)$ for some $0 \leq a < \infty$
  The second paper claims $p_n = o(\exp(n^\varepsilon))$ for some $0< \varepsilon < .2$ and makes the statement that the growth of $p_n$ increases as an exponential rate of the sample size as opposed to the first paper where the growth only increases as a polynomial rate of the sample size.

O and o are the big O and little o notation respectively. And an excellent explanation of the two topics is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1364444/difference-between-big-o-and-little-o-notation
It is my understanding that these are upper bounds to sets of functions, so to speak.  And that this notation is used to describe the behavior of $p_n$ as $n \to \infty$

My confusion happens here:  as I look at these functions $$\exp(n^\varepsilon) \cdots 0<\varepsilon < .2$$ and $$n^a\ldots0\leq a < \infty $$ it would seem that functions in the second set would grow faster-  that while the $p_n$ increases as an exponential rate of the sample size since we limit the values of $\epsilon$ to such a small values that in reality, the second expression leads to higher values of the $p_n$ for large $n.$  I'm sure I'm missing something, just not sure what. Can I really compare these two things directly.

Comment: Look at the limit of the first expression divided by the second expresssion and use L'Hopital's rule $\lceil a \rceil$ times.

Comment: @Bridge Much more simply, take logs of both sides and notice that the first gives a power function of $n$ while the second is logarithmic, and recall that any positive power eventually grows faster than the logarithm (an elementary result included in just about all Calculus texts).